# How to access TestNg parameters from Cucumber Scenario file (Change the scenario Name Dynamically)

Tags: cucumber

Currently, I have implemented  cucumber runner level parallel project using TestNG + Cucumber and it works really well. We are using allure for report generation but when I run the test cases in parallel imaging in 2 devices report will get replace since my scenario name is not unique in the feature file. Now I want to make my Scenario name dynamic so I want to put the Device name and Os version which I got from TestNg params function and access it in the Feature file. Here is my Runner file where I get parameters.

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import device.Device;
import device.DeviceFactory;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario;

@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/html/", "json:target/cucumber.json", "junit:TEST-all.xml" }, glue = {
        "steps" }, tags = { "@Mobile" })
public class ParallelRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({ "deviceName", "platformVersion" })
    public void executeParallelTests(String deviceName, String platformVersion) {

        Device device = new Device();
        device.setDeviceName(deviceName);
        device.setOsVersion(platformVersion);
        DeviceFactory.setDevice(device);
    }



}
```

I want to achieve something like this in my feature file

```
  Feature: SignUp
  @Android @IOS @Mobile
  Scenario: SignUp  ${"eviceName"}  ${"platformVersion"}
```

Can anyone let me know how this can be achieved in cucumber?

Comment: How r u running test cases in parallel ?first  Which Cucumber version and second you are trying to read parameters from feature file using TestNG, r u sure about this implementation.

Comment: @TheSociety I am using 1.2.5 Cucumber. Is it possible to inject device name into the feature scenario name?

Comment: I would request you to move to Cucumber v 4.x.x as you would be able to implement parallel execution smoothly and Cucumber 1.2.5 is too old. Your scenarios report would not be replaced during parallel execution and this mechanism would not work like reading parameters from feature file.

Comment: @TheSociety do you mean just update the cucumber version and all will be okay? I am doing Runner level parallelism not scenario level

Comment: When you say Runner Level you mean you want parallel execution per feature file not per scenario, please correct me ?

Comment: @TheSociety yup per feature